# Authenticate method not working in Spring Boot while using logi

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting a 403 forbidden, it's printing the first line system.out.println() in login service
I am using MySQL database, with arc

This is login service, login API linked to

```
public LoginSuccessStatus login(AppUser appUser) {
        System.out.println("safdsaf");
        LoginSuccessStatus lss = new LoginSuccessStatus("Either usrname or password is wrong", false);
        System.out.println(authProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                appUser,
                appUser
            )).isAuthenticated());
        System.out.println(appUser.getPassword());
        var user = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail());
        System.out.println();
            var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user.get());
            lss.setMessage("login success");
            lss.setStatus(true);
            lss.setToken(jwtToken);
            return lss;
    }
```

and this is the beans config to initialize authentication provider and PasswordEncoder

```
public class BeansConfig {
    
    public AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUDS() throws UsernameNotFoundException{
        return  (username) -> {
            return appUserRepository.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("no such user"));
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(getUDS());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

this is the Securityfilter which is permitted for login and signup

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain  sFC(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf((csrf) -> {
            csrf
            .disable();
        })
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests)-> {
            authorizeHttpRequests
            .requestMatchers("/appuser/signup","/appuser/login")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
        })
        .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> {
            sessionManagement
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        })
        .authenticationProvider(authenticatinProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        
        return http.build();
    }
```